# Magento API catalogProductList filter

Tags: magento-enterprise, api

I've been trying, without any success, to acquire a list of products via the API that meet a certain criteria.  Our catalog is made up of products which we stock in-house and some that we drop ship.  For those that we stock in house, 'manage stock' is set to 'yes' (1), and those are the ones I would like to get in my result set.  I've tried setting my complex filter a few different ways with no luck (one example below):

```
$filter = array (
    'complex_filter' => array (
        array (
            'key' => 'manage_stock',
            'value' => array ('key' => 'in', 'value' => 'Yes')
        )
    )
);

$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filter);
```

All variations of the above that I have tried result in a fatal error:

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Server] Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object
```

And the stack trace doesn't give me any info as to what I might be doing wrong.  Does someone have some insight into this, or if it is even possible?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Add the filter to your call

```
$result = $proxy->catalogProductList($sessionId, $filter);
```

Also I assume that you already have a `$sessionId` and you have your soap client setup `$proxy` Yeh?

Also the user that you login with the soap client with, ensure that has correct permissions.

Comment: Sorry, I should have included that in my post.  I'll fix that now.  I had been including the $filter, but removed it to make sure the filter was causing the problem (without the filter, the code works fine and I get all products returned).

Comment: Can you catch the soap fault correctly and give full output and code.

Comment: Also try a Boolean value of true instead of 'yes'.